# Clear values in global variable on button click in android

Tags: java, android

I have declared a **global integer variable 'add'** whose purpose is to add the values entered in the edittext 'e1'. The values are shown in textview 't11'. A button is created to reset the values of textview 't11' .
 How can I **clear** the integer **value** that is **previously held by 'add'.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView t11;
Button b3;
EditText e1;
int add,tankfuel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t11=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    b3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    tankfuel=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
add=add+tankfuel;
t11.setText(String.valueOf(add));
e1.setText("");
    }
});     
 b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t11.setText("");

                           //here the value held by add should be cleared


            }
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear.you want to clear the text view or **add** variable.

Comment: `YourActivityName.this.add = 0`

Comment: What is a global variable in Java?

Comment: GLobal Varible means you can access it in any method or in whole class anywhere,....................

Comment: you want to clear the t11 textview value

Comment: It seems the two `onClick` handlers do not refer to the same `add`. We cannot help without knowing your class structure. Where did you declare `add` and the two `onClick` listeners?

Comment: The value held by add variable should b cleared when i click on the button. The 'add' variable is globally declared. the two onclick listeners are inside onCreate

Comment: `add=0` should work fine. Try to add some log statements to see what the value really is.

Comment: instead of using `add=0` ..is there some other way that i can clear the memory held by `add`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        t11.setText("");

  }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to set the text in textview as blank ..I want to clear the value held in variable 'add'